# How should I convert between classes created using C++ templates?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template `SoundRecording.h`:

```
template <typename T>
class SoundRecording {
public:
    explicit SoundRecording(T init);
private:
    T data;
};

template <typename T>
SoundRecording<T>::SoundRecording(T init){
    data = init;
}
```

And I can create instances of this template class like this:

```
SoundRecording<int16_t> recording(INT16_MAX);
```

What is the best way to convert `recording` to a `SoundRecording<float>`?

I know I could use a simple method, for example I could declare:

```
SoundRecording<float> convertInt16ToFloat(SoundRecording<int16_t> input)
```

But I was wondering whether there was a more elegant way to achieve this using assignment or constructor operators.

*Updated following comments:* I am looking to define an explicit conversion. In the above example `recording.data` is equal to `INT16_MAX` after construction. After being converted to a `float` it should equal `1.0F`.

Comment: It's currently unclear what conversions you want to be available. Are you saying that you want `SoundRecording<T>` to be convertible to `SoundRecording<U>` if `T` is convertible to `U`? And do you want explicit or implicit conversions, and should it only work if `T` is implicitly convertible to `U`?

Comment: Depends on what you call "elegant". The way you described works; what exactly are you trying to improve?

Comment: To me the conversion seems like it should be the responsibility of the `SoundRecording` object, rather than a separate static method. Not really a fan of "utility" methods if I can avoid them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a templated conversion operator like

```
template<class U>
explicit operator SoundRecording<U>() { /*do the conversion here*/ }
```

Minimal code snippet that exemplifies the technique:

```
template<class T>
struct X
{
    template<class U>
    explicit operator X<U>() {return {};}
};

int main()
{
    X<int> x;
    auto y = static_cast<X<float>>(x); // conversion
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e4162ff061f8816)

As @Mooing Duck remarked in the comment, try to mark your conversion operators as `explicit` to avoid nasty un-wanted compiler-triggerd conversions.

You can go a bit further and enable your conversion only when `T` is convertible to `U` or vice-versa, via a combination of  [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and [`std::is_convertible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible), like so:

```
template<class U, 
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T, U>::value>::type* = nullptr>
explicit operator X<U>() {return {};}
```

Comment: prefer `explicit operator S...()`

Comment: Why not do the conversion as a constructor instead of a conversion operator?

Comment: @Justin You can also do that, but this allows conversion *after* construction if one desires.

Answer (score 2):

For an example of allowing this with a copy constructor instead of a casting operator:

```
#include <cstdint>

template <typename T>
class SoundRecording {
public:
    SoundRecording();

    template <typename U>
    SoundRecording(const SoundRecording<U>& other);

private:
    T *data;

    template <typename U>
    friend class SoundRecording;
};

template <typename T>
SoundRecording<T>::SoundRecording(){
    data = new T[10];
}

template <typename T>
template <typename U>
SoundRecording<T>::SoundRecording(const SoundRecording<U>& other){
    data = new T[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        data[i] = static_cast<T>(other.data[i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    SoundRecording<int16_t> recording16;
    SoundRecording<float> recordingFloat(recording16);
}
```